# Get a list of ids not present in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of ids, and I want to query a mysql table for ids not present in the table.

e.g.

```
list_of_ids = [1,2,4]
```

mysql table

```
id 
1
3
5
6
..
```

Query should return `[2,4]` because those are the ids not in the table

Answer (score 0):

since we cant view ur code i can only work on asumption

Try this anyway

```
    SELECT id FROM list_of_ids
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id
                     FROM table)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a horrible text-based hack:

```
SELECT
  substr(result,2,length(result)-2) AS notmatched 
FROM (
  SELECT
    @set:=replace(@set,concat(',',id,','),',') AS result 
  FROM (
    select @set:=concat(',',
      '1,2,4' -- your list here
    ,',')
  ) AS setinit,
  tablename --Your tablename here
) AS innerview  
ORDER BY LENGTH(result) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you represent your ids as a derived table, then you can do this directly in SQL:

```
select list.val
from (select 1 as val union all
      select 2 union all
      select 4
     ) list left outer join
     t
     on t.id = list.val
where t.id is null;
```

SQL doesn't really have a "list" type, so your question is ambiguous.  If you mean a comma separated string, then a text hack might work.  If you mean a table, then something like this might work.  If you are constructing the SQL statement, I would advise you to go down this route, because it should be more efficient.